# When a literal is passed to the constructor through a member function, why is the value not assigned to the member of the class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, member-functions, function-call

I am a beginner in C++. I am working on constructors. I am writing a simple a railway ticket booking program. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class Ticket
{
    char* name;
    long PNR;


    Ticket(char *pname, long pnr):name(pname),PNR(pnr)
    {
    }

public:
    Ticket()
    {
        name = NULL;
        PNR=0;
    }

    void booking()
    {
        char *n;
        n= new char[25];
        cout << "Enter Your Name: ";
        cin  >> n;
        Ticket(n,12345);
        cout << "Your Ticket is Booked." << endl;
    }


    void status()
    {
        long num;
        cout << "Enter PNR: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num == PNR)
            cout << "Ticket is confirmed" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Ticket is not confirmed" << endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Your PNR is " << PNR << endl;
        cout << "The PNR is alloted to " << name << endl;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int option;
    Ticket pass1;

book:
    cout << "Select an option: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Booking\t2. Status\t3.Print Info" << endl;
    cin >> option;

    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        pass1.booking();
        break;
    case 2:
        pass1.status();
        break;
    case 3:
        pass1.print();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Entry. Exiting" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << "Do you want to check another ticket?" << endl;
    cout <<"1. Yes\t2. No" << endl;
    cin >> option;

    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        goto book;
        break;
    case 2:
    default:
        cout << "Exiting" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }


return 0;
}
```

In the member function, `booking()`, I call the constructor and pass n and 12345. However, n is passed to the constructor is saved to the member variable "name" but 12345 is not saved to the member variable "PNR". I did not find any error in the code. Why is this happening?

Comment: Note for a beginner: 1. get a good book 2. avoid new/delete (if not, pair these strictly)

Comment: You are not passing a string-literal.  You're passing a pointer to a modifiable `char` buffer.   Also, calling `booking` more than once will result in a memory leak.  You should use `std::string`, not just for the memory leak issue, but also you won't limit yourself to a name that is 24 characters in length (plus the terminating null) if you use `std::getline(cin, string_var);`  And please rid yourself of that awful `goto` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ticket(n,12345);` is creating a temporary `Ticket` and then discards it.  It does not set the member variables for the currect `Ticket`.  To set the variables `booking()` should look like

```
void booking()
{
    name = new int[25]
    cout << "Enter Your Name: ";
    cin  >> name;
    PNR = 12345;
    cout << "Your Ticket is Booked." << endl;
}
```

I would suggest that you use a [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of a char array as you need to remember to delete the array in the destructor and you need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator.  If you use a `std::string` then all of the defaults will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ticket(n,12345);
```

does not re-call the constructor for the current element, it creates a temporary `Ticket` initialized with `(n,12345)` and immediately discards it.

In general, you can only construct an object once. After construction completes, you cannot call a constructor for that object again.

Instead you can just assign to your member variables by using their name:

```
void booking() {
    PNR = 42;  // This will change the member PNR of the current instance
    // ...
}
```